# Bind event to Iframe inside aspx page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, dom-events

I have an aspx page in one of my .Net Web application. Inside which I am having iFrame that show a URL content.

My requirement is to restrict user from using right click option. I have already implemented the Javascript code for this, but it is working only outside the iFrame on the page NOT inside the iFrame i.e. when I run the project and right click somewhere outside the frame it shows proper error message but when I right click inside the frame it, allows the user to right click (View source).

Any idea how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You can't do it unless you control the source of the iframe (in which case you'd have to add your code there too). Why do you want to stop people right clicking? With dev consoles and firebug, technical people will find a way round anyway.

Comment: This is the requirement. Is there any way I can bind the method to iFrame's mousedown & mouse up event?

Comment: Not unless you control the source of the iframe.